# HyperLinkedModelSerializer: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django and drf and I'm trying to setup a simple api to return the List and Detail views of the "Personality model. I want the urls to use the slug field instead of the default pk.

It works fine when using the default "pk" field for resolving urls but when i tried using the slug field via lookup_field,
I'm getting the following error:

> [ERROR] 'ImproperlyConfigured at /personality/
>   Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name >"personality-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in >your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this >field.'

models.py:

```
class Personality(models.Model):
personality_name = models.CharField(
    "Influential Person", unique=True, max_length=100
)
slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
info = models.TextField("Information")
trivia = models.TextField("Trivia")

def __str__(self):
    return self.personality_name

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.slug = slugify(self.personality_name)

    super(Personality, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class PersonalityViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

queryset = Personality.objects.all().order_by("id")
serializer_class = PersonalitySerializer
lookup_field = "slug"
```

serializers.py:

```
class PersonalitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name="personality-detail", lookup_field="slug"
)

class Meta:
    model = Personality
    fields = ("pk", "personality_name", "url", "slug", "info", "trivia")
    read_only_fields = ("pk", "slug")
    # lookup_field = "slug"
    # extra_kwargs = {"url": {"lookup_field": "slug"}}
```

quotes/urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"personality", views.PersonalityViewSet)
urlpatterns = [path("", include(router.urls))]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
path("", include("quotes.urls")),
path("api-auth", include("rest_framework.urls", namespace="rest_framework")),
```

]